Abi Encode with Signature - String memory as parameter to function
I'm trying to do
abi.encodeWithSignature(
                "mint(address, string **memory**)",
                receiverAddress,
                tokenURI
            )

The function definition is like this:
function mint(address to, string memory tokenURI) public {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenURI);
        unchecked {
            tokenId++;
        }
    }

Do I need to add memory keyword while encoding or not?
It will be a great help if someone can explain me that.
Thanks in advance.

You don’t need to add memory keyword. Also, you’ve to remove any spaces.
So, it should be:
abi.encodeWithSignature(
                "mint(address,string)",
                receiverAddress,
                tokenURI
            );


Thank you very much, especially for going one step ahead and suggesting removal of whitespaces.

You’re welcome, Mayank. Kindly please accept the answer, if it helped you. Happy coding!
